# I've checked out a .css style sheet in Sharepoint Designer 2007 and don't know how to check it back in

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, css

I have a .css style sheet checked out in Sharepoint Designer 2007 somehow that I need to check back in but I don't know where to check it back in. Where does this style sheet reside so that I can find it and check it back in with the changes I've made?

This is a SP 2007 environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the Style Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @LunizWVU (posted as CW)
I was able to check the style sheet back in by myself using the actual SharePoint site by going to: 1. Site Actions 2. View All Site Content 3. Style Library 4. Select .css style sheet and checking it i